# "Isn't it?" Vs "Is it not?"

Tags: interrogatives, contractions

In the spoken English I used to hear to people who ask "Isn't it?" while it is apparently supposed to be "Is it not?". What is the explanation for that? Is it a mistake or there's an explanation for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Why is it not red?" or "Why isn't it red?"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11260/why-is-it-not-red-or-why-isnt-it-red) Also consider [How to choose a proper contraction “it's not” versus “it isn't”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/how-to-choose-a-proper-contraction-its-not-versus-it-isnt).

Comment: Do you mean question tags?

Comment: @Rompey: I'm sure OP simply wonders why the standard contraction uses a different *word order* to the "full" version.

Comment: The answers for this question may help: [Position of not in questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24982/)